# $\sin^2$ notation and uses of the alternative.

Tags: reference-request, notation, education

So I was taking my calculus class and I was shocked by the following:

Apparently its a convention for

$\sin^2(\alpha)=(\sin(\alpha))^2$

As opposed to what I thought made more sense which was

$\sin^2(\alpha)=\sin^2(\alpha)=\sin(\sin(\alpha)))$.

This made more sense to me because for two reasons.

reason 1 : $\sin^{-1}(\alpha)\neq(\sin(\alpha))^{-1}$ 
in other words it denotes the inverse function of sine, not the multiplicative inverse of sine of a number.

reason 2:

writing $(\sin(\alpha))^n$ is a lot faster than writing $\underbrace{\sin(\sin(\dots(\sin(}_{n\text{ of these}}\alpha\underbrace{))\dots))}_{n\text{ of these}}$

So I guess that the justification for this is that the composition of the sine function is not very useful.

My question is, are there any interesting things that actually do use composition of trigonometric functions? is there an agreed upon definition for the composition of trigonometric functions?

Regards.

Comment: The convention is correct, what you thought made more sense, is actually wrong. Taking the sine of a sine is not sin²   I guess better get used to it....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please feel free to write (if you wish) $(\sin x)^2$ and $\arcsin x$ to avoid this confusion.  But learn to recognize the standard notations $\sin^2 x$ and $\sin^{-1} x$ for them, when others use these.

You are correct that $\sin(\sin(x))$ is not often seen (because it is not often useful).  Do not write $\sin^2 x$ for it, unless you are writing a specialized paper, and include this convention at the beginning.  Also do not write $\sin^{(2)} x$ for it, as that usually means
$$
\frac{d^2}{dx^2} \sin x .
$$

Notations you can use for $(\sin \circ \;\sin)\, x$ are $\sin^{[2]} x$ and $\sin^{{\displaystyle \circ} 2} x$.  But even then, it would be best to include the explanation.

Comment: do you know of any uses for composition of trigonometric functions?

Comment: Very few.  One that I do know (for kiddies with a new calculator):  Start with any numbe and repeatedly press the "cos" button; what do you get? (Be sure you are in radian mode.)  Now explain why this works...

Comment: @Omnitic: In the field of analytic number theory one often encounters the logarithm function iterated 2, 3, and 4 times, and I've sometimes seen the notation $(\log \circ \log) = {\log}_{2},\;$ $(\log \circ \log \circ \log) = {\log}_{3},\;$ $(\log \circ \log \circ \log \circ \log) = {\log}_{4},\;$ etc.$\;$ Thus, $\;{\sin}_{n}$ seems like a natural and easy-to-use notation for the $n$'th iterate of the sine function. Of course, if you use this, you'd want to define it--don't assume the reader will know the notation.

Comment: @Omnitic: In this [31 December 2007](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=6049132) sci.math post, and this [11 October 2008](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=6456600) sci.math post, iterated sine's appear. It is not really an application, however, but instead it is a puzzle-math type problem that I suspect someone just made up (rather than something that arose from a legitimate mathematical investigation).

Answer (score 0):

$\sin^2 x=(\sin x)^2=(\sin x)(\sin x)$ and that is not equal to $\sin(\sin x))$
Similarly: $(\sin x)^{-1}=\frac{1}{\sin x }$ but $\sin^{-1}x=\arcsin x$ Lastly, $\sin(x^2)=\sin(x*x)$.

Comment: This does not actually answer the question. The OP is aware (though surprised by) the convention.

Comment: Yes, that may be true, but he was...shocked! And so I got shocked as well. I just thought to clear it out to be on the safe side.

Answer (score 0):

Conventions are what somebody decided they'd be.

For a parallel, consider that mathmeticians say `i = sqrt(-1)` while electrical engineers say `j = sqrt(-1)`.  For EE's, `i` was already in use for current.

Note, however, that in naming unit vectors, `i` parallels the `x` axis, `j` parallels `y`, etc.  And since the complex plane LOOKS like an x-y coordinate system, it would seem more logical that `sqrt(-1)` be called `j`.

Just learn to live with it.  All the rest of did.

Comment: It's also a convention to call the unit vector parallel to the $x$-axis $i$, etc., so I'm not sure how much more logical it is to use $j$ for the imaginary unit, especially when there is an 'i' in 'imaginary'.  Although, I agree with the point overall ... it is something we just have to get used to.